# Type Error: QApplication(List[str]): not enough arguments

Tags: python, pyqt, typeerror, pyqt5, qapplication

Disclaimer: I am relatively new to programming, and especially new to Python.
I am trying to learn to build a GUI with PyQt5 and I keep receiving the error "Type Error: QApplication(List[str]): not enough arguments" when trying to launch my application... I don't see any arguments that would make sense to use, and the ones that I have tried(that would be valid) then cause it to say " module.**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)"

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class Main(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('HelloWorld')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtWidget.QIcon('Image.png'))
        self.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
gui = Main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing your code I noticed that you are confusing `QApplication` with some Widget.

> The `QApplication` class manages the GUI application's control flow
>   and main settings. **It's Not a Widget.**

In your case you could use a widget, for example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('HelloWorld')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Image.png'))
        self.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
gui = Main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Note: I have changed `self.setWindowIcon(QtWidget.QIcon('Image.png'))` to `self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Image.png'))`*

Answer (score 1):

`QtWidgets.QApplication.__init__()` requires at the very least a list of arguments to be passed to it when starting. My guess is that your code fails when you try to initialize your own `Main` class that calls `QtWidgets.QApplication` init. Try:

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # allow it to receive any number of arguments
        super(Main, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # forward to 'super' __init__()
        # etc.

# when initializing:
gui = Main(sys.argv)
```